# Status bar color not changing according navigation bar's color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I confronted with the problem. I have a project both on iOS6 and iOS7. In whole app I'm using UINavigationBars. But my application's status bar doesn't change his color according my navigation bar's background image. My code of navigation bar's customisation:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImageForNavigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navBar {
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBackgroundImage"];
    backgroundImage = [backgroundImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
    [navBar setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [navBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
}
```

For iOS6 it's work fine. How can I resolve this problem for iOS7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image needs to be 66 pixels (or the @2x version 132).  If it is 44, you will still get the little bar up top.

Comment: Nice answer. It helps. But I can't understand why it works for iOS6 but not works for iOS7?

Comment: I've been asking myself that question on a number of items in iOS land lately.  I know of no official documentation about this, but saw another user post describing the situation.  When I made changes to my apps, it worked great.